# Non-standard formats of sheets without frames in the eskdx class

Tags: pagestyle

Good afternoon!

Can someone tell me, faced with the problem of displaying frames on non-standard sheets.

I need several A3 landscape sheets in the document. A table is placed on the sheets, the sheets should be without frames.

Before the table, I wrote the following `\ESKDlandscapeAIII{\ESKDstyle{empty}\ESKDstyle{plain}`. But it turns out that I don't have a frame on the first sheet, but there is a frame on the second sheet. Here's what it looks like for me.

[image]

Although according to the eskdx documentation, `\ESKDstyle{emty}` should continue until I disable it.

Preamble of the document:

```
\documentclass[russian,utf8,floatsection,equationsection,emptystyle,14pt]{eskdtext}
% Declaring a document of the eskdtext class (for more information, see the description of the eskdx package)
%russian - text in Russian, utf8 - encoding of the UTF-8 document
%floatsection - numbering of tables and figures taking into account the chapter number, equationsection - the same for formulas
\usepackage{longtable} % In the document, we use the longtable package to create tables
\usepackage{graphicx} % We use graphics in the document
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png,.jpg}
\graphicspath{ e:\Diplom\picture_for_diplom }
\usepackage[warn]{mathtext} % Russian letters in formulas
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\No}{\textnumero}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex,unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{eskdfreesize}
\newcommand{\Strut}[1]{\rule{0pt}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Struts}[1]{\rule{5mm}{#1}}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
%\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.}
%\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.}

% alignment content by 1 urvon ------
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\l@section}{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.1em}}
\renewcommand{\l@subsection}{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.1em}}
\renewcommand{\l@subsubsection}{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother
%--------------- long hyphen
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{emdash}{\textemdash}
\captionsetup[figure]{name={Figure},labelsep=emdash}
\captionsetup[table]{name={Table},labelsep=emdash}
%---------------
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} % Setting the line spacing

\usepackage{setspace} %arbitrary line-by-line inetrval

\ESKDsectStyle{section}{\normalsize} % Chapter headings in regular font
\ESKDsectStyle{subsection}{\normalsize} % Section headers in regular font
\ESKDsectStyle{subsubsection}{\normalsize} % Subsection headers in regular font
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % for uline underscores
\ULdepth = 1mm % distance from the line to the text above/below
\usepackage[numberbottom]{eskdplain}
\ESKDstyle{empty}% off. numbering

\AtBeginDocument{%
\setlength{\parindent}{12.5mm} % Paragraph indentation.
}
\usepackage{lscape}
\ESKDsectStyle{section}{\MakeUppercase} %header style
\ESKDsectAlign{section}{Center} %header alignment
\ESKDsectSkip{section}{12pt}{12pt}% header margins
\ESKDsectSkip{subsection}{12pt}{12pt}% header margins
\ESKDsectSkip{subsubsection}{12pt}{12pt}% header margins

\addto\captionsrussian{\def\refname{Bibliographic list}}% renaming the list of references to the bibliographic list
```

Maybe someone has encountered such a problem and will tell you.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `\graphicspath{ e:\Diplom\picture_for_diplom }` should be `\graphicspath{ {e:/Diplom/picture_for_diplom} }`